# How to Output a sequence configured via random pieces using pointer arrays

Tags: c

I am new to coding and we're just learning pointers, and I'm unsure of why this code is not storing the bits of the sentence to the sentence array throughout the program, or why it is not able to print the data,

This is for a school assignment, and I normally just spend hours attempting different methods, but I figure it will be better to ask for advice so i can learn to do this correctly.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "string.h"
#define SIZE 4

void nounPick(const const char *nPTR, char *sPTR );
void verbPick(const const char *vPTR, char *sPTR );
void prepPick(const const char *pPTR, char *sPTR );
void artiPick(const const char *aPTR, char *sPTR );

int main(void){

   char *noun[SIZE];
   char *verb[SIZE];
   char *prep[SIZE];
   char *arti[SIZE];
   char *sent[SIZE];

   noun[0] = "cat ";
   noun[1] = "dog ";
   noun[2] = "truck ";
   noun[3] = "plane ";
   noun[4] = "skateboard ";

   verb[0] = "drove ";
   verb[1] = "jumped ";
   verb[2] = "ran ";
   verb[3] = "walked ";
   verb[4] = "flew ";

   prep[0] = "to ";
   prep[1] = "from ";
   prep[2] = "over ";
   prep[3] = "under ";
   prep[4] = "on ";

   arti[0] = "a ";
   arti[1] = "one ";
   arti[2] = "some ";
   arti[3] = "any ";

   const char *nPTR = noun[0];
   const char *vPTR = verb[0];
   const char *pPTR = prep[0];
   const char *aPTR = arti[0];
   char *sPTR = sent[0];

   srand( time(NULL));
   for(int c = 0; c< SIZE; c++)
        *(sent + c) = 0;

   nounPick(nPTR, sPTR);
   verbPick(vPTR, sPTR);
   prepPick(pPTR, sPTR);
   artiPick(aPTR, sPTR);

   printf("Made it through the picking\n");
   printf("Your Random Sentence Is As Follows:\n");

   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        if(*(sent + i) == 0)
            i = SIZE;
        else
            printf("%s", *(sent + i));
   }

   return 0;
}

void nounPick(const const char *nPTR, char *sPTR ){

    int i = 0;
    int l = rand() % 5;
    printf("%d, is L\n", l);

    do{
            switch(*(sPTR + i)){
                case 0:
                *(sPTR + i) = *(nPTR + l);
                break;

                default:
                i++;
                break;
            }
    } while (i < SIZE);
}

void verbPick(const const char *vPTR, char *sPTR ){

    int i = 0;
    int l = rand() % 5;
    printf("%d, is L\n", l);

    do{
            switch(*(sPTR + i)){
                case 0:
                *(sPTR + i) = *(vPTR + l);
                break;

                default:
                i++;
                break;
            }
    } while (i < SIZE);
}

void prepPick(const const char *pPTR, char *sPTR ){

    int i = 0;
    int l = rand() % 5;
    printf("%d, is L\n", l);

    do{
            switch(*(sPTR + i)){
                case 0:
                *(sPTR + i) = *(pPTR + l);
                break;

                default:
                i++;
                break;
            }
    } while (i < SIZE);
    printf("\n\n%s\n\n", sPTR);
}

void artiPick(const const char *aPTR, char *sPTR ){

    int i = 0;
    int l = rand() % 5;
    printf("%d, is L\n", l);

    do{
            switch(*(sPTR + i)){
                case 0:
                *(sPTR + i) = *(aPTR + l);
                break;

                default:
                i++;
                break;
            }
    } while (i < SIZE);
}
```

Comment: You arrays have *four* elements, yet you initialize *five* elements (except for `arti`). Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Also note that for *any* array or pointer `a` and index `i`, the expression `*(a + i)` is *exactly* equal to `a[i]`.

Comment: And the indirection isn't correct regardless. All `char *sPtr = sent[0];` does is load an indeterminate pointer value into `sPtr`. The point at `sent[0]` was never set to anything meaningful at that point. Sending that `sPtr` on to the pickers is futility (and you wouldn't want to anyway).

Comment: And when you do `char *sPTR = sent[0];` the elements of `sent` are *uninitialized* and have *indeterminate* values. So the pointer `sPTR` is invalid and can't be used.

Comment: Generally, it seems you have some rather big misunderstandings about how pointers work, because a lot of your code just doesn't make sense. Please take some time to read through your text-books (and perhaps get more) and start with even simpler examples and assignments.

Comment: Your string arrays are all defined for just four elements; all but one have five elements assigned. `noun[4]` for example is out of bounds.

Comment: "this code is not storing the bits of the sentence to the sentence array" What makes you think so?

Comment: "it is not able to print the data" What makes you think so?

Comment: If you want to "learn to do this correctly" start by explaining each code line to yourself in detail. If you find you cannot go back to the corresponding chapters of your text book and the exercises you did for them. Play with that kind of line, alter it, see what happens.

Comment: `const const char *` is the same as `const char *`.  Did you mean `const char* const`?

Answer (score 0):

Run your code in a debugger.  It has multiple flaws:

At:

```
char *sPTR = sent[0];
```

`sent` is uninitialised, you then pass `sPTR` it to `nounPick()` and other functions where it is dereferenced and accessed with undefined results (throws an exception in my case in Visual Studio's debugger).

Even if you move the initialisation until *after* the loop that assigns sent, the line:

```
switch(*(sPTR + i)){
```

Takes a null pointer, offsets it then dereferences it.

To be honest beyond identifying this problem which is probably only the first hurdle, unpicking what the intent of this code is and how it was intended to work is probably pointless.  Making your solution work is just too complicated.  There is some stylistically weird code in it that may be course style or it may be contrived to demonstrate pointer operations (where array indexing would be more appropriate).  There are also elements of poor or ill-advised design in any case.

I suggest you encapsulate your string data in the picker functions and simplify them considerably as follows:

```
const char* nounPick()
{
    static const char* noun[] = { "cat", "dog", "truck", "plane", "skateboard" } ;
    int i = rand() % (sizeof(noun) / sizeof(*noun)) ;

    return( noun[i] ) ;  // or "noun + i" if that is the intent of the exercise 
}
```

... and similarly for the other picker functions.  That way each element can have different length lists and each picker knows the length of its list from the number of initialisers rather than some single common `SIZE` that may not be correct for all arrays (and isn't in your case for all but the `arti` array).

Then to output:

```
printf( "%s %s %s %s %s\n", artiPick(), nounPick(), verbPick(), 
                            prepPick(), nounPick() ) ;
```

The code will be much safer, simpler, and easier to follow.  It may however not meet the assignment requirements which may be contrived to exhibit specific aspects of pointer manipulation.  It is a rather poor teaching method if that is the case - introducing bad coding style to teach some aspect of the language is unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

With different initialization and with direct printing:

```
 char *noun[] = {"cat", "dog", "truck", "plane", "skateboard" };
 char *verb[] = {"drove", "jumped", "ran", "walked", "flew" };
 char *prep[] = {"to", "from", "over", "under", "on" };
 char *arti[] = {"a", "one", "some", "any"};

 srand(time(0));

 int i = 12;
 while(--i >= 0)
      printf("%s %s %s %s\n",
                        arti[rand() % 4],
                        noun[rand() % 5],
                        verb[rand() % 5],
                        prep[rand() % 5]);
```

The amount of words per category is hardcoded in the `%` operation. `sizeof arti / sizeof*arti` would be how to get it back, if you don't know and don't have it stored as `n_arti`.

With e.g. 6 nouns in a array size 10 you would take the "6", not the allocated size.

Instead of `printf` there could also be an assignment to a `char *sentence[4]` like `sentence[2] = verb[rand...]`. But these four words have to be looped or spread out also.

Just to make sure this is intended, and because it is fun, here the output:

```
any dog walked under
one cat jumped under
one truck walked from
a cat ran under
some dog jumped under
any skateboard walked over
some plane drove to
some skateboard ran from
some dog ran to
a dog ran on
one dog walked to
one cat walked from
```

---

`#define SIZE 4`

This should be N_WORD_CATEG or so; it is the size of the sentence array made from one word from each category.

---

**const**

The string literals can or should be declared `const` to generate compiler warnings when used as non-const.

`const char *sentence[]`

To declare the base lists themselves as constant even:

`char const*const noun[]`

This prevents doing `noun[1] = "mouse"` afterwards (which technically is OK: "dog" is lost but not overwritten)

This can be written in many ways - the `const*const` has the advantage of focusing on `char` and `noun[]`.

---

Well this can be easily extended: just copy-insert an "arti" and a "noun" line to get longer sentences.

```
printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s\n",
                         arti[rand() % 4],
                         noun[rand() % 5],
                         verb[rand() % 5],
                         prep[rand() % 5],
                         arti[rand() % 4],
                         noun[rand() % 5]);
```

The "4" sticks with the "arti" line. But now there are already one and a half places to change if you add an article.

Now it starts to really make sense:

```
some cat jumped to one cat
one skateboard walked on some dog
one plane flew under one skateboard
```

Comment: Suggest:  `arti[rand() % (sizeof(arti)/sizeof(*arti)]`,  then you can arbitrarily add strings to any array and it will work without any other modifications.